# Change the color of all red shapes and lines to black in visio

Tags: vb.net, visio

Hi I am trying to change the following

> everything with red Background should be changed to black background
>
> everything with red Line color should be changed to black line color
>
> everything with red Font color should be changed to blue font color

Is this doable with a Macro?

I tried several stuff but that was all nonsense and in the end I as not able to change the color nor get the color of a shape to check it.

The shapes used are all the same standard rectangles with round borders and connectors. *But that should not be the point of the question.*

Comment: and are you targeting a particular shape (or shapes) in a specific stencil or template?

Comment: @braX As said it was nonsense. It was not more than getting all the elements, loop over them and try to get some info out of them. _Without any success_

Comment: @JohnGoldsmith Just rectangles and connectors

Answer (score 0):

That code can helps!

```
Sub ttt()  
Dim shp As Shape  
For Each shp In ActivePage.Shapes  
   If shp.Cells("FillForegnd") = 2 Then shp.Cells("FillForegnd") = 0  
   If shp.Cells("LineColor") = 2 Then shp.Cells("LineColor") = 0  
   If shp.Cells("Char.Color") = 2 Then shp.Cells("Char.Color") = 4  
Next  
End Sub
```

But in versions 2007 and newer occurs troubles, because shape with red color of line/fill/font can use themes. In this case in shapesheet cells you can find values like **THEMEGUARD(RGB(255,0,0))**
Also you can read this thread [VBA Code for Shape Color Changes on Double Click](http://www.visguy.com/vgforum/index.php?topic=7066.0)